# MASM 8086 gibberish in front of text

Tags: assembly, macros, masm

I am getting into Assembly programming, and I have started to use MASM.  I defined a macro for printing, and another for string input.  It seems to work fine, but printing the string will not work if I use the macro, and I'm not sure why.

```
;Zanglang

.model small
.stack 200h

init macro
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
endm

fin macro
    mov ah, 04ch
    int 21h
endm

print macro str
    mov ah, 9h
    lea dx, str
    int 21h
endm

strinp macro

        mov ah, 0Ah
        mov dx, offset buff
        int 21h                 

        mov si, offset buff + 1
        mov cl, [ si ]          
        mov ch, 0               
        inc cx                  
        add si, cx            
        mov al, '$'
        mov [ si ], al            

        ;Print the value of buff
    print newl
    print buff + 2
    print newl

        ;This works!!!
    mov ah, 9h
        mov dx, offset buff + 2
        int 21h

endm



.data

prompt db 10, 13, "Enter your string: $"
newl db 10, 13, "$"

buff        db  26
        db  ?
        db  26 dup(0)

.code
start:

init

print prompt

strinp

fin
end start
end
```

Comment: A proper description (or copy/paste of the text from your terminal window) instead of just saying "strange gibberish" would have made the answer a lot easier for other people to see.  I assumed you must have had a pointer error somewhere and were printing some binary data, not just overwriting normal ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

I used MASM 6.15 to assemble your sample and then ran the binary under DOSbox.

Your code works, but the strange behavior originates from your incorrect newline sequence.  DOS needs a CRLF instead of a LFCR which is what you have.  In this order, DOS ignores the LF (10) and then processes the CR (13).  Once DOS processed your CR, the cursor is placed at the beginning of the same line.  Then your input string prints over the beginning of the "Enter your string" prompt.  To fix the problem, just reverse your newline sequence as follows:

```
prompt db 10, 13, "Enter your string: $"
newl db 10, 13, "$"
```

*to the following:*

```
prompt db 13, 10, "Enter your string: $"
newl db 13, 10, "$"
```

OUTPUT (once fixed):

```
C:\>dostest
Enter your string: howdy
howdy
```

Comment: My problem is not the text "writing over" itself, it's more that it will skip to a new line, print an arrow, an ASCII emblem, and then print it (for example, I typed "howdy", and it put [arrow][clover]howdy)

Comment: I ran your [updated] MASM 6.15-assembled program on a DOS 6.22 machine in addition to DOSBox and it ran without problems.  Please supply the following: 1> What version of MASM are you using?  2> What is the linker and version you are using?  3> What version of DOS are you using?  4> What are the command lines you are using to build the executable?